# I don't know why my C code always returns 128

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a code to determine the largest prime number less than a number n. I'm not sure why my code always returns 128 whatever n is input.

So this is what I did. Input n, then run a `for` loop for i from 1 to n. Then run another `for` loop nested in the first one, for j from 1 to square root of i. If i is divisible by j, then break the nested loop, otherwise assign the largest prime number to i. Repeat.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    long i, j, n, largest_prime;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%ld", &n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j*j <= i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0)
                break;
            else
                largest_prime = i;
        }
    }
    printf("The largest prime is: %ld", largest_prime);
    return 0;
}
```

It always returns 128.

Comment: It's time to learn how to use a debugger

Comment: You never assign to `largest_prime` so printing it is undefined behaviour. You just happen to get `128`.

Comment: It's impossible for your assignment statement to ever be reached, since `i % j == 0` is always true when your if statement is reached.

Comment: Think about the conditions under which you should be setting `largest_prime` equal to `i`. Then look closely at your code.

Comment: @Paulpro I assigned it to i though. Because I want to find the prime number, so if the `i % j == 0` is true then it is not a prime number.

Comment: @KhanhThan1002, as @Paulpro said, `i % j` is alsways `0`, since `j = 1`.

Comment: Tip to avoid overflow (`j*j`) use `for (j = 2; j <= i/j; j++)`.  Likely faster as good compilers emit efficient code for proximate `i/j` and `i%j`

Comment: 1 is not a prime, so keep that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. first of all inner loops should start with 2 instead of 1. i.e `j=2`
2. you should not make `largest_prime=i` in else case, that is like as soon as you are finding that any number cant divide `i` then it is a prime which is wrong.

Below i have modified your code to find largest prime less than n. But this can improved further by making outer loop `for(i=n;i>=2;i--)` and breaking the loop as soon as we hit a prime number.

```
int main(void)
{
    long i, j, n, largest_prime;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%ld", &n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int isPrime = 1;
        for (j = 2; j*j <= i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0){
                isPrime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime==1)largest_prime = i;
    }
    printf("The largest prime is: %ld", largest_prime);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggest `long  largest_prime = something;` to prevent UB in `printf("%ld", largest_prime);` when `n < 1`.   Also this code reports "largest prime is: 1" when `n==1`.